# Ler arquivo na pasta Assets

Tags: android

Como eu faço para ler um arquivo de texto dentro da pasta Assets em um projeto Android?

Ex:

```
my_project/assets/file.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no meu caso eu pego uma imagem no assets

mais dai vc muda o metodo de acordo com oque vc quer....

```
public Bitmap getAssetFile(Context context, String fileName) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    Log.i("teste", "getAssetFile: fileName: "+fileName);

    try {

        File filePath = context.getFileStreamPath(fileName);        
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath.toString());
        return bitmap;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.i("teste", "getAssetFile: "+e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Você pode utilizar um método como este:**

```
public static String getFileTextFromAssets(Context context,String[] pFolders, String pFileName) 
{

    // Stringbuilder que sera utilizado no processamento
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    // Cria o nome do arquivo a ser carregado
    for (String s : pFolders) {
        sb.append(s);
        sb.append("/");
    }

    // Adiciona o nome do Arquivo
    sb.append(pFileName);

    try 
    {

        // Obtem o contexto definido globalmente e abre o arquivo do Assets
        InputStream is = context.getAssets().open(sb.toString());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String s = null;

        // Instancia do stringbuilder que sera utilizada para leitura do arquivo
        sb = new StringBuilder();

        while ((s = br.readLine()) != null)
            sb.append(s + "\r\n");

        br.close();
        is.close();
        return sb.toString();

    } catch (IOException e1) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e1);
    }

}
```

**Considerando que dentro da pasta Assets você pode ter outras pastas, basta passar um array de String com o caminho e o segundo parâmetro é o nome do arquivo:**

```
String fileText = getFileTextFromAssets(this,new String[] { "" }, "file.txt");
```

Comment: Na declaração de getFileTextFromAssets você tem três parâmetros, entretanto na chamada do método você passa apenas dois argumentos. Outra coisa, faltou o "t" em "getFileTextFromAsses". Fora isso, sua resposta está correta.

Comment: Sim, pq fiz na mão agora rsrsrs, mas você está certo. Vou corrigir.